# How to Deduct Family Health Care Premiums Under Side Business

Tags: united-states, taxes, tax-deduction, health-insurance, schedule-c

I am an employee of a company and I have health insurance through them, pre tax.  My company only pays for me so I have private insurance for my wife and kids.  I also have a side business, and was told by a tax professional last year that I can write off the private insurance premiums for my family (not me) under my side business, so long as the the write-off amount does not exceed the amount of profit by the business.  Note, I am the only employee of the business.

Is this true?  How do I accomplish this?  I assume it is somewhere on the Schedule C form.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, not on schedule C, better. Its an "above the line" deduction (line 29 on your 1040). [Here's the turbo tax article on it](http://turbotax.intuit.com/tax-tools/tax-tips/Self-Employment-Taxes/Deducting-Health-Insurance-Premiums-If-You-re-Self-Employed/INF12128.html). The [instructions for this line](http://www.irs.gov/instructions/i1040/ar01.html#d0e5170) set certain limitations that you must take into the account, and yes - it is limited to the net profit from the business.

> One of the following statements must be true.
>
> - You were self-employed and had a net profit for the year.
> - You were a partner with net earnings from self-employment.
> - You used one of the optional methods to figure your net earnings from self-employment on Schedule SE.
> - You received wages in 2011 from an S corporation in which you were a more-than-2% shareholder. Health insurance premiums paid or
>     reimbursed by the S corporation are shown as wages on Form W-2.
>
> The insurance plan must be established under your business. Your
>   personal services must have been a material income-producing factor in
>   the business. If you are filing Schedule C, C-EZ, or F, the policy can
>   be either in your name or in the name of the business.

Comment: OK, so I am not self employed and the plan is in my wife's name.  If I'm understanding correctly, that means I am out of luck.  Is that right ?

Comment: Yes. I thought you have a side business, isn't that what you said?

Comment: I do have a side business, but is a sole proprietorship.  I bring in anywhere from $10K to $15K a year, but it is not an S-Corp, I don't have an office, and I don't have employees.  A tax person I talked to said I could write off their premiums under this business.

Comment: sole proprietor is self employed by definition, what's the problem? You have to have performed personal services (i.e.: investment business or rental, for example, doesn't count), but if you file schedule SE - you're good. In the instructions there's a worksheet on how to calculate the allowed deduction amount.

Comment: OK, I just read this (http://www.irs.gov/publications/p334/ar01.html).  Until now, I thought Self Employment meant, that was your primary income source and you had no employer.  That's great news!  Are there any other tax perks of being self employed?

Comment: One more thing...that article states "You can only claim the health insurance premiums write-off for months when neither you nor your spouse were eligible to participate in an employer-subsidized health plan".  My employer only subsidizes my health insurance, but I could add my family to the plan if I wanted at full cost to me.  Does that exclude me from claiming this?  If so, what about months where because of Open Enrollment restrictions, I can't add them?

Comment: @ctorx that I think you should ask your tax adviser. These are details pertaining your specific situation that we shouldn't be discussing here.